# How to add a new variable in order invoice product table snippet in cs cart?

Tags: cs-cart

In product table snippet there are already many variables like price, total, subtotal, tax etc.

I want to add a new variable using addon or hook. Any help will be highly appreciated if anyone has idea of it.

Comment: Did you got any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

general doc is here
https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/core/documents/snippets.html

as practical example, you can check for 2 schemes:
1. app/addons/reward_points/schemas/documents/order.post.php - it extends Order variable
2. app/addons/suppliers/schemas/snippets/order_products_table.post.php - it extends snippet for products table in invoices

Answer (score -1):

You could modify or add inside your own addon at path:

```
/app/addons/my_changes/schemas/snippets/order_products_table.post.php
```

the code that looks something like this:

```
$schema['custom_tax_name'] = array(
    'class' => '\Tygh\Template\Document\Variables\GenericVariable',
    'data' => function (\Tygh\Template\Snippet\Table\ItemContext $context) {
        $data = array();
        $product = $context->getItem();
        $data['tax_name'] = getTaxName($custom_val); //you could have function here to get whatever your needs are

        return $data;
    },
    'arguments' => array('#context', '#config', '@formatter'),
    'attributes' => array(
        'tax_name'
    )
);
```

This is what you are looking for. After this, you need to clear your cache. You will see inside product table in "Total" for exmample, the new variable you already create with name like this:

```
{{ custom_tax_name.tax_name }}
```

These names are for the above example purposes. You may have whatever your needs are with something useful and understandable.

[image]

Comment: Is that by chance a copy of a different existing answer?